# How create function to universal pagination?

Tags: javascript

How create generic function to form the pagination array.The function receives 2 numbers (totalPage, currentPage). Need to do as in the example "Only page numbers" on https://pagination.js.org Started doing the implementation, but so far unsuccessfully [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/insider73/7u1j9Let/2/)

```
let calculatePaginationItems = (totalPage,currentPage) => {
    let arr = new Array;
    if(totalPage > 6) {
          for(let i = currentPage; i < totalPage + 1; i++) {
    
            if((currentPage < ((currentPage + 3) - i) + currentPage) || i > totalPage - 3) {
              arr.push(i)
            }
            if(i === currentPage + 4) {
              arr.push('...')
            }
          }
        } else {
          for(let i = 1;i < totalPage + 1;i++){
            arr.push(i)
          }
        }
        console.log(arr);
    }
    
    calculatePaginationItems(100,50)
    calculatePaginationItems(100,99)
    calculatePaginationItems(7,7)
```

Comment: What is the desired output of this function? And what's wrong with its current output?

Comment: @DBS a am edit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a loop and some checks for the length of the wanted pages.

For a different padding, you could address the third parameter. Default value is three pages.

```js
const calculatePaginationItems = (totalPage, currentPage, padding = 3) => {
    const
        start = Math.max(1, currentPage - padding),
        end = Math.min(currentPage + padding, totalPage),
        pages = [];

    if (start > 1) pages.push(1);
    if (start > 2) pages.push('...');

    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) pages.push(i);

    if (end < totalPage - 1) pages.push('...');
    if (end < totalPage) pages.push(totalPage);
    return pages;
}

console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 1));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 3));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 4));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 5));

console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 50));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 50, 1));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(100, 99));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(7, 7));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(5, 5));
console.log('');
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 1));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 3));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 4));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 5));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 6));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 7));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 8));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 9));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 10));
console.log('');
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 1, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 2, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 3, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 4, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 5, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 6, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 7, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 8, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 9, 2));
console.log(...calculatePaginationItems(10, 10, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow reduce the number of displayed items?
[1 ... 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 ... 100] -> [1 ...  49 50 51 ... 100]

Answer (score 0):

What is the "Only page numbers" example you are talking about? Where does it come from?
If I understand correctly your fiddle code, you want to have the 6 page numbers around the current page number right? So, if you have `calculatePaginationItems(100,50)`, you want to get `[48,49,50,51,52,53]`.

It is always a good idea to add unit tests when you ask a question, so we can answer more accurately what you want to get out of your function.

EDIT: I saw your edit and I am working on a proper answer.